# Error using calcHist with mask

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting this error when trying to use calcHist with a mask: `error: (-215) mask.size() == imsize && mask.channels() == 1 in function histPrepareImages`

```
bgr_split = cv2.split(img)

hist_size = 256
c_range = [0, 256]
rows, _, _ = img.shape

b_hist = cv2.calcHist(bgr_split[0], [0], mask, [hist_size], c_range, False)
```

It should be said that it works when there is no mask applied to the function.  The shape of the actual image is (246, 300, 3) while the shape of the mask is (246, 300, 1).

The mask is created by using the area contained within a contour.

```
r, h, ch = img.shape
mask = np.zeros((r, h, 1), np.uint8)
contours, hier = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv2.cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, (0, 0))
cv2.drawContours(mask, contours, 0, 255, cv2.cv.CV_FILLED)
```

Can anyone spot the problem here?  Cheers

Comment: Please provide a code snippet for creating a mask image.

Comment: @OpenMinded Code for creating the mask image added

Answer (score 4):

try adding brackets around the first input argument.

> > b_hist = cv2.calcHist([bgr_split], [0], mask, [hist_size], c_range, False)

I had the same error of "error: (-215) mask.size() == imsize && mask.channels() == 1 in function histPrepareImages" and after adding brackets for the first argument, the error was gone.

Comment: That's some stupid thing there but this approach worked for me too. Thanks jhch

Answer (score 0):

Your line for calculating the histogram should be

```
b_hist = cv2.calcHist(bgr_split, [0], mask, [hist_size], c_range, False)
```

The second argument ('[0]') already indicates that you want to make the histogram for the first channel only.